# Vertical Alignment of tikz picture in a table cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I apologize in advanced for asking a question that has been asked before.  I have read the other posts on SE about vertical alignment but I'm very new to Latex and had difficulty understanding them.  I have a two column table.  One column with text and the other with a tikz picture.  Below is a simplified example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|c|}
\hline
Hello World &
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-3, -3) rectangle (3,3);
\draw (-3,-3) -- (3,3);
\draw (-3,3)  -- (3,-3);
\end{tikzpicture} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

When I compile using pdflatex from texlive on Crunchbang (debian), Hello World is aligned to the bottom of the first cell. I thought that using p{...} in my column parameters would top align. Can someone explain why this doesn't work and the proper way to do this?

Comment: updated my answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 13):

This problem is due to the text on the left being pushed down by the tikzpicture. It can be solved by using [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.5\textwidth}|c|}
\hline
Hello World &
\adjustbox{valign=t}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-3, -3) rectangle (3,3);
\draw (-3,-3) -- (3,3);
\draw (-3,3)  -- (3,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** OK, here are some more explanations to the nature of the problem you encountered.

In LaTeX, the `tabular` environment align the contents of adjacent cell such that their reference points are on the same horizontal line. What the option `p{width}` does is to surround the content of the column with `\parbox[t]{...}`. On the other hand, by default, picture generated by `tikz` will have their baseline at the bottom. This is why the text on the left get push down by the picture in your example.

The `baseline=0pt` argument of `tikz` adjusted this by forcing the the position of the the x-axis onto the baseline. Alternatively, you can also use `baseline=(current bounding box.north)` to put the upper end of the picture at the reference line (or surround the picture by `\raisebox{-171.11646pt}{...}`, though I'm not entirely sure why isn't the parameter `-6cm` which is equivalent to `-170.07874pt`, though it may have something to do with the default `PGF` line width which is `0.4pt`). Moreover, what the `\vspace{0pt}` at the beginning does is to move the reference point of the cell to that position, and it is why you seemingly achieved top alignment.

Here is a picture that demonstrate the differences among three options of tikzpicture (without `baseline`, with `baseline`, and with `baseline=(current bounding box.north)`), notice the position of the reference point in each case (marked using `layouts` package):

[image]

Now let's go back to my answer. The `adjustbox` with option `valign=T` does what essentially the same as `baseline=(current bounding box.north)`, that it moves the baseline to the top of the picture. Nonetheless, `valign=t` moves the baseline `0.7\baselineskip` away from the top, so you get a better alignment (`adjustbox` works with `tabularx` too):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

After I posted I discovered that my problem was actually related to vertical alignment of the tikzpicture.  If I replace that portion of the above code with multi-line text I get the alignment I wanted.  Searching along those lines I discovered several answers on SE that I was able to combine to solve my problem.  I also switched to tabularx because I prefer the X syntax over p{...}.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|}
\hline
Hello World &
\vspace{0pt}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\draw (-3, -3) rectangle (3,3);
\draw (-3,-3) -- (3,3);
\draw (-3,3)  -- (3,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

There are two keys: one add [baseline] (default is 0pt) to the tikzpicture.  If that is all I do I get the text aligned roughly to the middle of the picture.  Someone recommended using \vspace{0pt} and I tried that and found it to move the text to the top.  I'm not clear on why this solution works but it does.