# Table, Tikz picture in the left, text in the right: how to vertically align?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, vertical-alignment

I would like a table with tikzpictures in the left column and explanatory notes in the right column. What can I do improve the vertical alignment of the row contents in the following example? Intuitively, both the picture and the text should be aligned to be at the top.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tabular}{cp{6cm}}
Column title & Column title 
\\ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\tkzDefPoint(-7,-4){A}
\tkzDefPoint(-5, 0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(-3,-2){C}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C A,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
& 
This looks really bad. What can I do to improve the alignment of the text?
\\ 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\tkzDefPoint(-7, 4){A}
\tkzDefPoint(-5, 0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(-3, 2){C}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C A,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
& 
Flipping it vertically does not help either. How can I improve the format?
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?): [Vertical Alignment of tikz picture in a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127027/134144)

Answer (score 2):

using `baseline=(current bounding box.north)` as `tikzpicture` option should help:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cp{6cm}}
Column title & Column title
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,baseline={([yshift=-1.8ex]current bounding box.north)}]
\tkzDefPoint(-7,-4){A}
\tkzDefPoint(-5, 0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(-3,-2){C}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C A,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
&
This looks really bad. What can I do to improve the alignment of the text?
\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,baseline={([yshift=-1.8ex]current bounding box.north)}]
\tkzDefPoint(-7, 4){A}
\tkzDefPoint(-5, 0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(-3, 2){C}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C A,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
&
Flipping it vertically does not help either. How can I improve the format?
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```